# How to share information between HTML and Dynamic Selections? - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, cordova

I am new to the AngularJs framework and I need some help with a couple questions. 
I have tried to find information on the internet and by looking through tutorials but many of them are incomplete.

I have another problem: I must make a Web Application that will run on Phone Gap, but I don't know how to use a client side language. And I cant use JSP, etc
I read a Json file that's hosted on the server and parsed by Angular. Now when I want to do something with information I cant find how.

**First**: I want to take the number of the people that use the Tablet/Movil (like a loggin but not a loggin)

HTML part

```
<body>

<div ng-app="index" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <p>
        Indicar numero del grupo <input type="text" ng-model="numero">
    </p>
    <a href="sugerencias.html">Continuar</a>
</div>
```

Looking on internet I find that you can use the following controller:

```
var app = angular.module('index', []);
app.factory("MyService", function() {
return {
    data : {}
};

app.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, $location, MyService) {
$scope.goTo2 = function() {
    MyService.data.numero = $scope.numero;
    $location.url("sugerencias.html");
};

app.controller("Ctrl2", function($scope, MyService) {
$scope.numero= MyService.data.numero;
```

And the HTML

```
<body>
        <h1>Carta de Pedidos</h1>

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <p>El numero de personas interesadas es : {{numero}}</p> 

    </div>
```

Obviously it doesn't work, and I need a small example that can help me to understand How to send the params to other
 HTML

**Second problem**:

When I make a table with information by Json (dynamic information), that has a check box in each row, How can i know which row has been checked?

It`s possible that this question will be easy to experts but I am sure that I have not found the answer on the internet yet so I'm trying here.

Thanks to all people!!! =)

Answer (score 0):

After looking many information on other pages and documentation, Angular its only used to make ONE PAGE webs. This kind on work its not eficcient on this framework. You must use differents divs that share information between them but dont move the information to other HTMLS.